# I need to make a ajax call from jsp page to struts action class to get some data like name search

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I need to make a ajax call from jsp page to struts action class to get some data like name ,search .I have to show names if and only if thy have entered at least three characters.if the three characters are less than three we don't have to make ajax call.i used autocomplete api for this .i tried by using

code:

```
function f1{
var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
alert("hey it is inside on change function");
    if(x.length>=3){
        $( "input#name" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'getVehicletrACstatusQuery.status'                      
        }); 
}
```

here it is not calling ajax x.length is showing null i invoked this function onchange() and  even i tried with document ready function..but no use
please help me out....

Comment: how you have written tag??

Comment: sorry i  did not get you..

Comment: `name ` is text box 's ID??  how you have written text box in html??

Comment: yes name is text box id i have declared like     <td><s:textfield cssClass="cnt-form-style-mine1" id ="TRno" name="TRno" value="%{TRno}" onfocus="this.value = ''" theme="simple" size="20" tabindex="10"/></td>

Comment: you should use `document.getElementById("TRno").value;`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you've some syntax errors on your function definition, try with something like:

```js
function f1(){
    var x =  $( "#name" ).val();
    alert("hey it is inside on change function");
    alert("x.length: " + x.length);
    if(x.length>=3){
        $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'getVehicletrACstatusQuery.status'                      
        }); 
     }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<input id="name" onchange="f1();"></input>
```

Also from [jquery ui documentation autocomplete source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) documentation:

> String: When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that
>   string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can
>   be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The
>   Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query
>   string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should
>   use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is
>   set to "http://example.com" and the user types foo, a GET request
>   would be made to http://example.com?term=foo. The data itself can be
>   in the same format as the local data described above.

So since you're using a string for `source` parameter on `autocomplete` check that the URL using `GET` return the expected data on JSON format.

There is another options on how to use the source on `autocomplete` so this is not what you expect check the [autocomplete documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Hope this helps,

Comment: ok ,thanks for your response ,just now i got to know there is some specification for this type we can use minLength:3

Comment: ok ,thanks for your response ,just now i got to know there is some specification for this type we can use minLength:3

Comment: @user3528870 sorry I don't understand your comment